# Okay, is *this* monadic?

Tags: javascript, monads

I'm putting a security layer in front of a document-oriented and I needed a reasonably abstract way for the application to define what new documents and what updates to existing documents are legal for a particular user.

The particular issues are
-- The documents are defined (at least in transit) as JSON objects, so the rules may be hierarchical and so the  rule-engine has to work recursively.  For example, the Employee object may have a sub-object called Compensation and that sub-object has a field called PayPeriod that must be one of 'weekly', 'biweekly', or 'monthly'.
-- it runs Node.js and some rules need to read from input (for example, to read more user data from a database) , so it has to run in continuation style.

So what I came up with is this: each rule is a function that takes the current value, the proposed new value, and a callback that is invoked with the value to be used.  That value can be one of the two inputs or some third value calculated by the rule.  Here's one rule:

```
var nonEmpty = function(proposedValue, existingValue, callback) {
    callback( (proposedValue.length > 0) ? proposedValue : existingValue);
};
```

This rule would only allow you to set or replaces this field with a non-zero-length value.  Of course, that only makes sense for string values (ignore lists for the moment, so we need a rule to enforce string-ness):

```
var isString = function(proposedValue, existingValue, callback) {
    callback( ( typeof(proposedValue) === 'string') ? proposedValue : existingValue);
};
```

In fact, that seems like a common sort of problem, so I wrote a rule generator:

```
var ofType = function(typeName) {
    return function(proposedValue, existingValue, callback) {
    callback( ( typeof(proposedValue) === typeName) ? proposedValue : existingValue);
    };
};

var isString = ofType('string')
```

but I need a way to string rules together:

```
var and = function(f1, f2) {
    return function(proposedValue, existingValue, callback) {
    f1(proposedValue, existingValue, 
       function(newProposedValue) {
           f2(newProposedValue, existingValue, callback);
       });
    };
};

var nonEmptyString = and(isString, nonEmpty);
```

So the rule for an adminstrator to update an Employee record might be:

```
limitedObject({
   lastName : nonEmptyString,
   firstName : nonEmptyString,
   compensation : limitedObject({
      payPeriod : oneOf('weekly', 'biweekly', 'monthly'),
      pay : numeric
  }
})
```

`limitedObject` (like `ofType`) is a rule-generating function, and it that only allows the fields specified in its argument and applies the given rule to the values of those fields.

So I wrote all this, and it works like a charm.  All my bugs turned out to be errors in the unit tests!  Well, almost all of them.  Anyway, if you've read this far, here is my question:

I've been febrilely studying monads and my reading inspired me to solve the problem this way. But, is this truly monadic?

(Possible answers:  "Yes",  "No, but that's okay because monads aren't really the right approach for this problem", and  "No, and here's what needs to change".  Fourth possibilities also welcome.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this does not appear to be monadic. What you've defined appears to be a mini-DSL of rule *combinators*, where you have simple rules like `ofType(typeName)` and ways of combining rules into bigger rules like `and(rule1, rule2)`.

In order to have a monad, you need some notion of context in which you can put any value. You also need the following operations:

1. A function `wrap(x)` for putting *any* value into some default context.
2. A function `map(f, m)` for applying a function `f` to transform the value within `m` without altering the context.
3. A function `flatten(mm)` for flattening two layers of context into one.

These operations must satisfy certain "obvious" laws:

1. Adding a layer of context on the outside and collapsing gives you back what you started with.

   ```
   flatten(wrap(m)) == m
   ```
2. Adding a layer of context on the inside and collapsing gives you back what you started with.

   ```
   flatten(map(wrap, m)) == m
   ```
3. If you have a value with three layers of context, it does not matter whether you collapse the two inner or the two outer layers first.

   ```
   flatten(flatten(mmm)) == flatten(map(flatten, mmm))
   ```

It is also possible to define a monad in terms of `wrap` as above and another operation `bind`, however this is equivalent to the above, as you can define `bind` in terms of `map` and `flatten`, and vice versa.

```
function bind(f, m) { return flatten(map(f, m)); }

# or

function map(f, m) { return bind(function(x) { return wrap(f(x)); }, m); }
function flatten(mm) { return bind(function(x) { return x; }, mm); }
```

It is not clear what the notion of context would be here, how you would turn any value into a rule. Thus the question of how to flatten two layers of rules makes even less sense.

I don't think a monad is a suitable abstraction here.

However there it is easy to see that your `and` does form a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) with the always-succeeding rule (shown below) as the identity element.

```
function anything(proposedValue, existingValue, callback) {
    callback(proposedValue);
}
```

Comment: *combinators* -- that was the name of the pattern I was looking for.  It felt very familiar.

Comment: This is the the most accessible explenation of the monad laws for Javascript devs I've ever seen!